# SQL SERVER - retornar colunas diferentes de um inner join na mesma linha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

Tabela **usuarios**

Tabela **usuariosacessos**

Na tabela `usuariosacessos`, cada linha possui o `id` do usuário, o nome da funcionalidade, e um campo informando se possui ou não o acesso.

No meu caso específico, preciso trazer apenas duas funcionalidades.

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
select u.codus, u.nome, ua.acessarForm from usuarios as u 
inner join usuariosacessos as ua on u.codus = ua.codUsu
where u.login ='SS' and u.senha = '10' and ua.funcionalidade in ('frmTablet_Add', 'frmTablet_Remove');
```

mas ele me retorna duas linhas (uma para cada funcionalidade)

Gostaria de trazer estes dados em apenas uma linha.

Existe alguma forma para fazer isso?

Comment: No caso ele está duplicando para o mesmo `id` 2 `funcionalidades`?

Comment: Não, são dois registros diferentes da tabela usuariosacessos, um para frmTablet_Add e outro para frmTablet_Remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em um caso simples como esse, de apenas duas colunas, você pode usar sub-selects, e criar as colunas manualmente. Em casos mais complexos, poderia fazer uma tabela pivotada.

Considerando seu modelo atual dessa forma:

```
create table usuarios 
( 
  id integer,
  nome varchar(50) );

create table usuariosacessos
(
  usuario integer,
  funcionalidade varchar(20),
  valor bit
);

insert into usuarios values (1,'usuario teste');

insert into usuariosacessos values (1,'frmTablet_Add',1);
insert into usuariosacessos values (1,'frmTablet_Remove',0);
```

O select com sub-selects poderia resolver seu problema:

```
select
    u.id,
    u.nome,
    (select 
         a.valor 
     from usuariosacessos a 
     where a.usuario = u.id 
     and a.funcionalidade = 'frmTablet_Add' ) as frmTablet_Add,
    (select 
         a.valor 
     from usuariosacessos a 
     where a.usuario = u.id 
     and a.funcionalidade = 'frmTablet_Remove' ) as frmTablet_Remove
from usuarios u
```

> Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/03265/2)

Comment: Perfeito! Muito Obrigado!